# Sqoop import/export issue

Tags: sqoop

I am looking to import/export selective columns using Sqoop with direct feature. Can I use `--column` attribute with sqoop export `--direct`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use --column with Sqoop export --direct.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pj--username root --password hr --table employees --columns 'FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME' --where 'SALARY>5000' --target-dir /datasqoop/sqoop3/ -m 1
```